# Replace Items with regex (kind of)

Tags: python, regex

I am handed a bunch of data and trying to get rid of certain characters. The data contains multiple instances of `"^{number}"` → `"^0"`, `"^1"`, `"^2"`, etc.

I am trying to set all of these instances to an empty string, `""`, is there a better way to do this than

```
string.replace("^0", "").replace("^1", "").replace("^2", "")
```

I understand you can use a dictionary, but it seems a little overkill considering each item will be replaced with `""`.

Comment: Have a look at `re.sub()`. Then replace a “^number“ `\^[0-9]+` or `\^\d+` with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the digits are always at the end of the string, have a look at the solutions below.

with regex:

```
import re

text = 'xyz125'
s = re.sub("\d+$",'', text)
print(s)
```

it should print:

```
'xyz'
```

without regex, keep in mind that this solution removes all digits and not only the ones at the end of a string:

```
text = 'xyz125'
result = ''.join(i for i in text if not i.isdigit())
print(result)
```

it should print:

```
'xyz'
```